# How to get a dynamic Textfields value in swift ios?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

i'm in trouble, Anyone can suggest How to get a value of dynamic textfields in swift ios ?
what should i do in buttonTapped function. look it

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var height = 50;
    for var i = 1; i <= 3 ; i++
     {
         var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.00, height: 140.00));
         myTextField.placeholder = "Enter Email Address \(i)"
         myTextField.center = CGPointMake(160, CGFloat(height))
         height = height + 50;
         self.view.addSubview(myTextField)
     }
    var btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 280, 150, 40));
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal);
    btn.setTitle("My Button Text!!", forState:UIControlState.Normal);
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);
    self.view.addSubview(btn);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
    println("Button Tapped!!!")
    // What should i do
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maintain array of textfields and access textfield object from Array to get Text in it.

Comment: You can define global textfield or you can define a  global list for storing textfields, or you can create custom button which stores textfield...

Comment: Thanks OMK, Tanriverdi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var arrayOfTextFields:[UITextField] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var height = 50;
    for var i = 1; i <= 3 ; i++
    {
        var myTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200.00, height: 140.00));
        myTextField.placeholder = "Enter Email Address \(i)"
        myTextField.center = CGPointMake(160, CGFloat(height))
        height = height + 50;
        self.arrayOfTextFields.append(myTextField)
        self.view.addSubview(myTextField)
    }
    var btn = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(50, 280, 150, 40));
    btn.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal);
    btn.setTitle("My Button Text!!", forState:UIControlState.Normal);
    btn.addTarget(self, action: "buttonTapped:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside);
    self.view.addSubview(btn);
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func buttonTapped(sender: UIButton!) {
    println("Button Tapped!!!")
    for textField in arrayOfTextFields{
        println(textField.text)
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

I created a global variable (an Array of UITextFields) to store the generated TextFields.
Now you can access them by iterating through that Array or take a special index

Answer (score 2):

Loop through self.view.subViews. Check the object in the loop using the as? operator. If it is a UITextField i.e. if the conditional cast is not nil, you can extract the text value and use it however you wish.

Comment: I could choose this way if I don't want/need to maintain a separate arrayOfTextFields!